# Create a self-signed certificate on Windows Server 2008 R2 with powershell v2.0

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, scripting, self-signed-certificate

I'm trying to create a self-signed certificate using power shell. I have tried using import-module PKI but seems like it's supported on powershell v3.0 onward .Is any other way I could create a self-signed certificate using powershell v2.0?

Comment: Is there any specific reason to stick with PowerShell 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

you could [download the Windows SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) and use [MakeCert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386968(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Please, read the page header in the referenced link. Makecert.exe is deprecated.

Comment: since he using Windows 2008 and powershell 2, makecert will work just fine. @CryptoGuy.

Comment: This one would be better: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Self-signed-certificate-5920a7c6. Makecert.exe was deprecated due to extremely weak and outdated cryptography. It was the solution in pre-Vista era, but things changed in Vista/2008 when they got completely new cryptography subsystem.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName 'www.fabrikam.com', 'www.contoso.com' -CertStoreLocation 'cert:\LocalMachine\My'
```

Comment: `New-SelfSignedCertificate` this command works on powershell v3.0 onward.

Comment: Also on Windows 2008R2, this command did not work even with PowerShell 3.0 (or 4.0, or 5.x)