# Installing PKI Client cmdlet on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, winrm

I wanted to install the PKI Client cmdlet on Windows 2008 R2. However, [from the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848636(v=wps.630).aspx), it's not available for Windows 2008 R2? Am I interpreting this correctly?

I was following along a [tutorial](http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/certificate-password-less-based-authentication-in-winrm) on configuring `winrm` and needed to run `New-SelfSignedCertificate`.

Comment: Duplicate question: https://serverfault.com/questions/795678/create-a-self-signed-certificate-on-windows-server-2008-r2-with-powershell-v2-0

Comment: Seems my google-fu failed me

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're interpreting that correctly.  Those cmdlets are not available for Windows Server 2008 R2.  If you click the "Other Versions" link on that page, you'll see what other versions of the OS contain PKI client cmdlets.  They were introduced in Windows 8/Server 2012.

[image]